# how to pollenrich from camel processor

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to pollenrich from camel processor?

earlier I used camel enpoint:

```
.pollEnrich("smb://domain;login:pwd@host/dir?password=pwd&preMove=backup&move=processed&moveFailed=error&charset=UTF-8", 1000)
```

But now I need to call pollEnrich from processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `ConsumerTemplate` to poll from endpoints: http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this: String text = x.getContext().createConsumerTemplate().receiveBody("smb://{{directoryPath}}", 2000,String.class); But after some time application gives me java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. Why this error may occur ? Earlied I have used .pollEnrich("smb://domain;login:pwd@host/dir?password=pwd&preMove=backup&move=processed&moveFailed=error&charset=UTF-8", 1000) and it were working without OutOfMemoryError error.

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html

Comment: Thank you. We are using SwitchYard. Could you, please, say is that correct way to have single instance of Producer/Consumer Template:

Comment: public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

   ConsumerTemplate template;
 public void configure() {
        from("switchyard://loadFiles")
                .routeId("file-processing")
                .process(x -> {
                    if(template==null){
                      template=  x.getContext().createConsumerTemplate();
                    }
                    String text = template.receiveBodyNoWait("smb://{{in_directory}}", String.class);
                    x.getOut().setBody(text);
                });
    
    }
    }